# How to build html table with two columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

http://jsfiddle.net/r6xGf/

The above link is my test. You can see that the columns are not equally divided into two.
I cannot use float for this because I will be using a page-break directive later on.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="head" colspan="2">Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%;">
            50% of table
        </td>
        <td style="width: 50%;">
            50% of table
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="last" colspan="2">Finish</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add  `colspan="2"` to the TR of head and last.

I have updated the fiddle